# Flutter App: Orientation Builder change causes Stream to have a ConnectionState of waiting instead of active

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, database-connection, flutter-web, screen-orientation

I have a simple app that pulls data from Firestore. I wanted to make it more user-friendly on web, so I added an OrientationBuilder that will place the Drawer next to the body when the orientation is landscape.

Here is my "Responsive Scaffold" widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  final AppBar? appBar;
  final Widget body;
  final Widget? drawer;
  const ResponsiveScaffold({
    Key? key,
    this.appBar,
    required this.body,
    this.drawer,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResponsiveScaffoldState createState() => _ResponsiveScaffoldState();
}

class _ResponsiveScaffoldState extends State<ResponsiveScaffold> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
        return portraitBuilder();
      } else {
        return landscapeBuilder();
      }
    });
  }

  Widget portraitBuilder() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: widget.appBar,
      drawer: widget.drawer,
      body: widget.body,
    );
  }

  Widget landscapeBuilder() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: widget.appBar,
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (widget.drawer != null) widget.drawer!,
          Flexible(
            child: widget.body,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside of the body that is pulling from Firestore is just a simple StreamBuilder that gives a ListView of all of the items.
I don't have any errors shown in the debug console but after some playing around and checking the connection state, I see that when I change from landscape to portrait orientation, or vice versa, the ConnectionState changes from active to waiting. Only when something new is added to the stream does it turn back to active.

If anybody can please help with this issue, I'd appreciate it!
If more information is needed as well please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, after much looking around, I have found the reason and solution.

The `OrientationBuilder` only builds ones and doesn't listen to any changes itself so when the `orientation` would change, it would not rebuild and would not try to pull the list correctly anymore.

The solution was to use `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` inside of a `Builder widget`. This listens for any adjustments and then rebuilds fully when the `orientation` would switch.